# Transform AST in UglifyJS

Tags: javascript, transform, abstract-syntax-tree, uglifyjs

I am using UglifyJS to parse, minify and transform JS codes. One of my goal is to transform the AST by inserting new variable definitions. For example:

```
var x;
var y;
x = 1;
y = x;
x = 3;
```

I want to insert a new variable definition "var _x" into a random position, such as before the statement "y = x". The transformed code should be like this:

```
var x;
var y;
x = 1;
var _x = x;
y = _x;
_x = 3;
```

I have tried the TreeTransformer in UglifyJS. Updating the symbol reference to be the new one (x -> _x) is no problem. But I am unclear about obtaining the right position for the insertion with TreeTransformer. Can anyone share some insights? Some code examples would be better!

Comment: variable declarations are function scoped, and the interpreter should hoist them to the start of the function, so it doesn't matter where you inject the new declaration so long as its in the right scope. Hope that's a useful bit of information. Also, this sounds like an experiment with metamorphism in javascript uglification..... be a good person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');

fs.readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'source.js'), 'utf8').then(function (file) {
  var topLevel = UglifyJS.parse(file);

  var transformed = topLevel.transform(new UglifyJS.TreeTransformer(function (node, descend) {
    if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Toplevel) {
      node = node.clone();

      // Add new variable declaration
      node.body.unshift(new UglifyJS.AST_Var({
        definitions: [
          new UglifyJS.AST_VarDef({
            name: new UglifyJS.AST_SymbolVar({
              name: '_x'
            })
          })
        ]
      }));

      // Replace existing assignment statement with new statements
      var index = _(node.body).findIndex(function (node) {
        return node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_SimpleStatement &&
          node.body instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Assign &&
          node.body.left instanceof UglifyJS.AST_SymbolRef &&
          node.body.left.name === 'y';
      });
      var assignmentStatement = node.body[index].clone();
      node.body.splice(
        index,
        1,
        new UglifyJS.AST_SimpleStatement({
          body: new UglifyJS.AST_Assign({
            left: new UglifyJS.AST_SymbolRef({name: '_x'}),
            operator: '=',
            right: new UglifyJS.AST_SymbolRef({name: 'x'})
          })
        }),
        new UglifyJS.AST_SimpleStatement({
          body: new UglifyJS.AST_Assign({
            left: assignmentStatement.body.left.clone(),
            operator: assignmentStatement.body.operator,
            right: new UglifyJS.AST_SymbolRef({name: '_x'})
          })
        })
      );

      descend(node, this);
      return node;
    }

    node = node.clone();
    descend(node, this);
    return node;
  }));

  var result = transformed.print_to_string({beautify: true});
  return fs.writeFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'output.js'), result);
});
```

Here is the output:

```
var _x;

var x;

var y;

x = 1;

_x = x;

y = _x;

x = 3;
```

Uglify hoists variable declarations in its AST format, so I follow the same rule.